# Multipage TIFF -- How do I remove "Subfiletype" exif tag?

Tags: tiff, exif, exiftool

I'm having some trouble with the "Subfiletype" tag in a multipage PDF.   I'd like to remove the "Subfiletype" tag entirely, and make the PageNumber tag count like so: 0,1  . . 1,2 . . 2,3 instead of 0,6 . . 1,6 . . 2,6

This is what my EXIF tags look like currently (output by exiftool):

```
+ [IFD0 directory with 20 entries]
| 0)  SubfileType = 2
|     - Tag 0x00fe (4 bytes, int32u[1]):
|        31146: 02 00 00 00                                     [....]
| 1)  ImageWidth = 850
|     - Tag 0x0100 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
|        31152: 52 03                                           [R.]
| 2)  ImageHeight = 1100
|     - Tag 0x0101 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
|        3115e: 4c 04         
.
.
.
| 16) PageNumber = 0 6
|     - Tag 0x0129 (4 bytes, int16u[2]):
|        31206: 00 00 06 00
```

And this is my desired format:

```
+ [IFD0 directory with 16 entries]
| 0)  ImageWidth = 2496
|     - Tag 0x0100 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
|         6da8: c0 09                                           [..]
| 1)  ImageHeight = 4128
|     - Tag 0x0101 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
|         6db4: 20 10      
.
.
.
| 15) PageNumber = 0 1
|     - Tag 0x0129 (4 bytes, int16u[2]):
|         6e5c: 00 00 01 00
```

I've tried using exiftool to drop the tag, but it wouldn't.  I suspect that this tag is "required" (even though other images do not have it, and still work fine).

How do I drop the unwanted tag from the files in question?

Comment: I took the liberty of rephrasing the question so it isn't a software recommendation question, which are essentially verboten.  I hope this helps you.  Otherwise, this looks like a good question.